# ChartJS Bullet chart with text and color ranges and labels

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, bullet-chart

I have a requirement where I need to build kind of bullet chart with `ChartJS`, below is what I need to have.

[image]

I found this link but not sure:

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3735

> Any clue how if ChartJS supports this or if is possible to create it by hand usuing ChartJS?

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi, yes we end building a custom canvas html javascript component